# How to show seconds in the Android system UI status bar?

Tags: android

When I receive a bug report and a screen recording from QA, it's very hard to pinpoint the interesting part in the logcat with a one minute imprecision.

How to display the clock as hh:mm:ss in the status bar?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on ADB:

```
adb shell settings put secure clock_seconds 1
```

To change it back use:

```
adb shell settings put secure clock_seconds null
```

or

```
adb shell settings put secure clock_seconds 0
```

`null` just means the system default.

Comment: I think this is only works on a rooted phone.

Comment: @SeifEddineSlimene Thanks for your input! I just checked on my phone, which is not rooted, and it still works. Were you getting any error message?

Comment: No, I just typed the command "adb shell settings put secure clock_seconds 1" and I got no error message like it's working but in reality nothing happened and no seconds are displayed with time in the status bar.

Comment: @SeifEddineSlimene Hmm, that's interesting. Do other ADB commands work, such as `adb logcat`? Also, note that to run ADB on MacOS, Linux, or other UNIX-based systems, you need to run it as a relative path (like `./adb`) or an absolute path (like `/Users/john/ADB/adb`) unless it's on your PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

The utility is not accessible in the UI, but still exists in android!

1. Start System UI Tuner

   ```sh
   adb root
   adb shell pm enable com.android.systemui/.tuner.TunerActivity
   adb shell am start -n com.android.systemui/.tuner.TunerActivity
   ```
2. Select *Status bar*
3. Select *Time* (penultimate item)
4. Select *Show hours, minutes and seconds*

Comment: Maybe there is a faster way by setting a property, but I didn't find what property is involved

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this; people on androidforum were talking about System UI Tuner, so I went to the play store, typed that in, and d/l'd "system ui tuner shortcut".

Surely the adb solution will work too but this was quicker for me right now! :)  Then status bar, time, etc. like user rds said.